# Only getting up to 1 decimal place in result

Tags: c++, precision

In the code below I wanted the answer to be up to 2 decimal places but the result only has 1 decimal place. I already used the `setprecision`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    if (b > a && a % 5 == 0)
    {
        cout << ((b - 0.50) - a);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << b;
    }
}
```

How can I get 2 decimal places in the answer?

Comment: Ohh, it is `int a;`

Comment: *I already used the `setprecision`.*  There is no use of `setprecision` in the code provided.  Please provide your *real* code.

Comment: This is the _real_ code

Answer (score 3):

> *I already used the setprecision.*

Certainly you are not using it right, for two decimal places, regarldess of the integral part, you need to use `std::fixed`.

Example:

```
//...
if (b > a && a % 5 == 0)
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << ((b - 0.50) - a);
    //           ^^^^^^^^^^     
}
//...
```

Sample exec:

Input:

```
5
10
```

Output:

```
4.50
```